# Generating ticks for a large dataset truncates the ticks array, even when most ticks are null

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am using Angular Chart.js to generate `linear` charts which contain a very large amount of data (often north of 3,000 points). Each datapoint has an associated object with important information (stripped down, it contains a date, x-value, and y-value). Effectively, I want a tick on every point starting with a new month, containing the month and year (i.e. 'Jun 22'). The amount of data between each month is variable, so distributing the ticks evenly is impossible for my use case.

The problem here is that Chart.js doesn't like charts with more than 1000 ticks, even if those ticks are null or undefined. At most, I will only ever need the chart to have roughly 36 ticks displayed.

I have a utility function that returns a map of `{index: label}`, which will simplify having to filter the entire dataset every time I am creating a new tick (so for example it looks something like

```
{0: 'Jun 22', 405: 'Jul 22', 1295: 'Aug 22', etc...}
```

With the index being the x-value). Using that map, I've set `stepSize: 1` and modified the callback:

```
callback: (index) => {return theMap[index] || null}
```

Chart.js throws a warning that `scales.x.ticks.stepSize: 1 would result generating up to 3437 ticks. Limiting to 1000.` Even though most of those data points don't have an associated point in the map (and thus have a null tick), I guess chart.js still thinks it's a tick and then shows some strange behavior of which ticks it actually displays.

See example below, and notice that Jul 21, Aug 21, and Aug 22 are missing (Nov-Apr correctly hidden)

[image: Example of incorrectly displayed ticks]

There is a hacky workaround: set `stepSize: 5` and then modify the callback to check the bounds of the step:

```
callback: (label: number, index: number, values) => {
    for (let i = label - 2; i < label + 3; i++) {
        if (this.theMap[i]) return this.theMap[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

This reduces the number of ticks generated by a factor of 5, but would not display two ticks that are less than 5 units away from each other.

Curious if anyone has dealt with anything similar and knows of a solution to get consistent tick generation with large datasets.

Comment: Have you tried to use a time scale? If I understood well, I think you are using a category one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/PoaNjbp where 3000 items are added using the time scale. Hopefully I have understood well your use case.
Be aware the sample is using CHART.JS 3.
Using the `ticks.source: 'label'`, I can force CHARTJS to use the labels which are passed in the scale (pay attention to the `parser` option as well, needed to parse the labels of the ticks).

```
scales: {
 x: {
    type: 'time',
    labels: ['Sep 22', 'Oct 22', 'Nov 22', 'Dec 22'],
    ticks: {
      source: 'labels'
    },
    time: {
        unit: 'month',
        displayFormats: {
          month: 'MMM yy'
        },
        parser: 'MMM yy'
    }
 }
}
```